# FQL Searching for events for a specific venue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm a newbie to facebook API development. I've been searching for any posts similar to my one, but no success so far.
I would like to perform an FQL query, rquesting plublic events which are going to take place whitin a specific venue (ex. specific city "London") whitin the next days.
I know that venue is a column which is not aceptable to place under the "WHERE" caluse acording to FQL guide (only name and eid). The question is that, I don't know the names or event ids. That's what I'm trying to figure out!
Does anyone has come across a similar problem?
Any sugestions are more than welcome.

Thanks a milion!

Answer (score 0):

I know its not a FQL query but I make a request to

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" + city + "," + sstate + "&type=event&limit="